# FOSUserBundle - How are roles handled?

Tags: php, symfony, user-management

So, I've read through the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) for the bundle, but there's nothing describing how to list existing roles or to assign/change rolls for a specific user.  I need to be able to:

1. Assign a default role to a newly registered user.
2. Have admins and superadmins elevate and demote users.

   - This has a requirement of me being able to *see* what roles I can choose from.

So, how is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$roleHierarchy = $container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
$roles = array_keys($roleHierarchy);
$form = $this->createForm(new UserFormType($roles, $user->getRoles()), $user);
```

In your UserFormType you can add the roles field like this:

```
protected $roles;
protected $userRoles;

public function __construct($roles, $userRoles)
{

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $theRoles[$role] = $role;
    }
    $this->roles = $theRoles;
    $this->userRoles = $userRoles;

}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{               

    $builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => $this->roles,
                    'data' => $this->userRoles,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                ));

}
```